# Unescape string containing octal bit pattern

Tags: ruby

I'm having trouble unescaping a string containing an [octal bit pattern](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings) (`"\50\51"`) in Ruby.

I've tried [`String#undump`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-undump), [`JSON#load`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-load) and [`YAML#load`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html). They all don't seem to unescape octal bit patterns. [`Kernel#eval`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/eval) does this, but I'd like to avoid using it.

```rb
str = '"\\50\\51"'

# expected result (but insecure)
eval(str)
# => "()"

# doesn't handle octal bit patterns
str.undump
# => "\\50\\51"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just evaluate it like this:

```
s.gsub(/\\(\d+)/) { |v| $1.to_i(8).chr }
```

Where that interpolates the substitutions as octal (base 8 argument to `to_i`).